# Rigify addon does not do its job properly for my character

Tags: rigging, armature, add-on, rigify

I am new to the Rigify Addon. I have used it with my character, and it's not working well in some parts such as the face.

[image]

[Link to the blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xuVMzmQg5T63IP23p8FZaBoxlzRYfLA6)

Just give me some tips to improve my rig. You can also make some changes for improvement and share that.

Answer (score 1):

Your face is working badly because your head hasn't a good topology. Search (even in this site) for Head topology and edgeflow, or start trying to copy this example of good head topology.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to work with that topology but with good mesh deformation.